# Can't do .thumb on image, even though it's defined in image_uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4 and trying to run @post.image.thumb.url in my Posts#Show view but I get this error:

NoMethodError in Posts#show
Showing /home/vagrant/code/nonofficejobs/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #11 raised:

undefined method `thumb' for #
Extracted source (around line #11):
8
9
10
11
12
13
14

```
      <%= link_to @post.user.name, @post.user %>
    </small>
   <p><%= markdown_to_html @post.body %></p>
   <div><%= image_tag(@post.image.thumb.url) if @post.image? %></div>
 </div>
```

This is my image_uploader.rb:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  process resize_to_fill: [90, 90]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :tiny do
  #    process resize_to_fill: [20, 20]
  #  end

  version :small do
    process resize_to_fill: [30, 30]
  end

  #  version :profile do
  #    process resize_to_fill: [45, 45]
  #  end

  process resize_to_fill: [300, 300]

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [50, 50]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to chnage your code from

```
<%= image_tag(@post.image.thumb.url) if @post.image? %>
```

to

```
 <%= image_tag((@post.image.url(:thumb)) %>
```

Comment: Did this. Got this error:

ArgumentError in Posts#show
Showing /home/vagrant/code/nonofficejobs/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #11 raised:

Version thumb doesn't exist!
Extracted source (around line #11):
8
9
10
11
12
13
14

          
          `<%= link_to @post.user.name, @post.user %>
        </small>
       <p><%= markdown_to_html @post.body %></p>
       <div><%= image_tag(@post.image.url(:thumb)) if @post.image? %></div>
     </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
       <% if policy(@post).edit? %>`

Comment: try what i have suggested to you without using if @post.image?

Comment: Are you storing file in Amazon S3?

Comment: Yes, I'm storing the files in Amazon S3.

I tried it and got an error:
ArgumentError in Posts#show
Showing /home/vagrant/code/nonofficejobs/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #11 raised:

Version thumb doesn't exist!
Extracted source (around line #11):
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
          
          `<%= link_to @post.user.name, @post.user %>
        </small>
       <p><%= markdown_to_html @post.body %></p>
       <div><%= image_tag(@post.image.url(:thumb)) %></div>
     </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
       <% if policy(@post).edit? %>`

Comment: Have you already installed imagemagick? If yes you must post your S3 config or ensure that is done right and gemfile because what are you showing is good